# How can I check that new data extracts have the same structure?

Tags: r, testing, csv, etl

I work for a research consortium with a web-based data management system that's managed by another agency. I can download the underlying data from that system as a collection of CSV files. Using `R` and `knitr`, I've built a moderately complex reporting system on top of those  files. But every so often, the other agency changes the format of the data extracts and blows up my reports (or worse, changes it in a subtle yet nefarious way that I don't notice for weeks).

They'll probably never notify me when these things happen, so I suppose I should be testing more. I'd like to start by testing that those CSV files have the same structure each time (but allowing different numbers of rows as we collect more data). What's the best way to do that? `R` is my preferred tool but I'm interested in hearing about others that are free and on Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your files are just CSVs, here is an example (assuming you keep a reference file around):

```
reference.file <- read.csv("ref.csv")
new.file <- read.csv("new.file")

struct.extract <- function(df) {
  list(
    vapply(df, class, character(1L)), 
    attributes(df)[names(attributes(df)) != "row.names"]
  )
}
identical(struct.extract(reference.file), struct.extract(new.file))
```

This compares attributes of the data frame, as well as classes of the columns.  If you need to get more detailed on column format you can extend this easily.  This assumes the reports are not changing # of rows (or columns), but if that's the case, that should be easy to modify as well.